# ignoring coding standards with php-cs-fixer?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, php-cs-fixer

In php_codesniffer you can ignore coding standards for a block of code thusly:

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
$a = ($b[$c >> 5 ] & 0x0080) &
     ($b[$c      ] & 0x0100) & // here is a multi-line
                               // quote from some spec
     ($b[$c >> 20]         );
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```

I think that's waaaay more readable then, say, this:

```
$a = ($b[$c >> 5] & 0x0080) & ($b[$c] & 0x0100) & ($b[$c >> 20]);
```

Does php-cs-fixer let you ignore coding standards for blocks of code like php_codesniffer does?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, PHP CS Fixer allows you only to ignore given paths (you may configure it in config file).
It is not possible to ignore part of code inside file. If you want, do not hesitate to raise a PR with proposed feature implemented!